# Db2 stored procedure returns either empty result set or show "No suitable driver found" error

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I am totally got stuck on this DB2 stored procedure & java routine thing and would like to ask and see if anybody see some similar and get a solution for it. Basically, I am trying to write some java routines, package them into a jar and copy it into a DB2 instance. Then on the DB2 side, I defined some stored procedures to call to my java routines, so that I can trigger them with db2 commands like `db2 "call sp_1(param1, param2)"`.

So for those java routines that don't return anything or just return primitive data type, i.e., sting, the associated stored procedures work totally fine. The problem is with java routines that return a **ResultSet**. To simply test java routine returns ResultSet, I wrote a dummy java routine like below (my real java routine will be reading some local files and generate/return real data as ResultSet to the stored procedure), using MockResultSet from [Mockrunner](https://github.com/mockrunner/mockrunner) package to return some dummy ResultSet .

```
public static synchronized void listUsers(ResultSet[] result) {
    MockResultSet rs = new MockResultSet("UserGroups", "cursor");
    rs.addColumn("User", new String[] { "user1", "user2" });
    rs.addColumn("Team", new String[] { "team1", "team2" });
    result[0] = rs;
}
```

on the stored procedure side, I defined a procedure like this (added `java.sql.ResultSet[]` in the parameter list according to this [IBM doc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=db2-definition-java-routine) regarding java routines.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LIST_USER ()
SPECIFIC JDBC_ONE_RES_SET
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
NOT DETERMINISTIC
LANGUAGE JAVA 
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
NO DBINFO
FENCED
THREADSAFE
READS SQL DATA
PROGRAM TYPE SUB
EXTERNAL NAME 'MYJAR:test.listUsers(java.sql.ResultSet[])'
```

With this, when I tried to do `db2 "call LIST_USER()` on the db2 instance after connect to db, I am getting this. It returns 0 which seems indicate that the stored procedure executed successfully, but seems like no result set is returned....

```
[20:55:06][test][~]$ db2 "call LIST_USER()"

  Return Status = 0
```

I also tried to return real data through SQL queries in my java routine by following some db2 sample java routines like [this](https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/blob/master/java/jdbc/SpServer.java#L822), but when I call the procedure, it throws the error below.

```
[01:07:51][test] $ db2 "call LIST_USERS()"
SQL4302N  Procedure or user-defined function "LIST_USERS", specific name
"LIST_USERS" aborted with an exception "No suitable driver found for
jdbc:default:".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

looking at the error, I think it failed at [getConnection](https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/blob/master/java/jdbc/SpServer.java#L833) (tried both `jdbc:default:connection` and `jdbc:db2:connection`)as if the db2 jdbc driver is not present. But that's not true, as I have db2 jdbc driver copied over and when I `echo $CLASSPATH`, I see driver **`db2jcc4.jar`** is there.

So if anybody know why my MockResultSet is not returned in the first approach, or why stored procedure is throwing  "No suitable driver found" error in my second approach, please chime in and I will deeply appreciate your input here!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: "No suitable driver" suggests to me that the URL you use to connect to the database is not correct.  Do something simple: Write a Java function that connects to the database.  You can't progress on the stored procedure until you can do that.

Comment: @duffymo thanks a lot for the quick response! yeah, I tried to write a java class and try to connect to my db2 db, it worked fine. In my java test class, I was using a explicit URL like `jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/testdb` to connect to a real db. In the java routine, I tried both `jdbc:default:connection` and `jdbc:db2:connection` as URL, which suppose to obtain/inherit the nest connection(correct??) when they are called as stored procedure. but it gives me  "No suitable driver found" error. It's inside the same machine/envrionment.

Comment: Why are you writing a stored procedure in java that connects to the database?

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini Hi, Lennart, I am writing a java routine similar to this sample java routine https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/blob/master/java/jdbc/SpServer.java#L822. 
That java routine can be called inside a stored procedure like this https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/blob/master/java/jdbc/SpCreate.db2#L139. Then, the stored procedure can be exposed and used directly with command like `db2 "call sp_1()"`,. let me know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini BTW, Lennart, in my first approach, I used MockResultSet to wrap my actual data as ResultSet and return that to the stored procedure to display. That's actually my preferred approach as my java routine supposes to read some local files and fetch data. But somehow, on the stored procedure, it keeps return empty result... That's why I switched to the second approach where I insert my data into database, then select it and return to stored procedure, with the hope that it can return a real ResultSet to stored procedure. but now i am hitting by that weird driver issue...

Comment: I was thinking, why not write the procedure in SQL? Just curios since I don't know what your procedure is doing

Comment: "which suppose to obtain/inherit the nest connection(correct??) when they are called as stored procedure" - no, not correct.  You should not be creating a new connection every time you want to talk to a database.  They are expensive and slow to create.  The better solution is to create a pool of connections when you start your application and give it to the function when you call it.  I have no idea where you found that "jdbc:default:connection" string.  I don't think that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just some quick update on my thread. The `"No suitable driver found` error is gone now after I restart db2 engine. So looks like after reinstall the java routine jar, we will need to restart the db2, so that `CLASSPATH`, jar, etc can be loaded and updated correctly.

Comment: For fences routines CALL SQLJ.REFRESH_CLASSES() should be sufficient